# Is it possible to find out which hash algorithm was used in these strings?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I don't want to reverse it. I just want to be sure what hash algorithm was used on these strings (I'm not sure if it's md5):

```
d27918bcc2a8562dc4549c2c00111e66
889f071e04755db26579a19f4303654e
47a21a13ee822c1450155bd0033b0f1d
```

Is there a way to do it?

One of the source for the strings above is certainly: '9915757678'

Comment: Do you have the original strings?

Comment: Not that you'll be able to reliably 'reverse' them either... also, they do look like MD5 checksums, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Do you know what the original text was.  If so just try it.

Comment: I don't have the original text for all of them. But the source for one of these strings should be '9915757678'.

Comment: @Acacio Nerull: if you mean the original string is `9915757678`, this is the MD5 hash: `cd182d8bef0540595c9c4abb3e4d6557` which isn't any of those listed in your question...

Comment: I'm not going to ask where you got these numbers from, but I *will* point out that any half-competent programmer is going to salt the plaintext, precisely to defeat the sort of attack you're attempting.  Give up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're each 32 characters, so 128 bits. So it *could* be MD5.

However, there is no way to tell. Any hash function worth its salt will spread the hash values evenly throughout the entire output space, so if you have just a bunch of outputs, there's no way to tell hash functions apart.

Unless you can make some reasonable guesses about the input, and do some brute-forcing, of course.

Comment: "Any hash function worth its salt" - pun intended?

Answer (score 2):

It fits MD5() hash form (length-wise) but it could be just as well SHA1 hash stored in CHAR(32) field. As others have said - unless you have an example of input value. Then you could use a tool like this:
http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php
to generate hashes using several diffrent algorithms and try to find if any one fits.

You're even more out of luck, if there was salt added before hashing.

Answer (score 1):

No certain way, but this looks like MD5.

Comment: @neoneye The decryptor I used was somehow weird, I removed the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on size, these could be one of **ntlm or md4 or md5**.
I know I'm too late here!, but posting this as I didn't see this possible answer.